# How to upload image to Firebase during sign up?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, formik

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase storage. The problem is that since the user has not signed up yet, I don't have their `uid`.

I depend on `onAuthStateChanged` to get the user id and upload an image to their bucket, but so far it hasn't turned out well.

```
const { userObject } = useContext(Context) //trying to get the uid from here

onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        async function writeToFirebase() {
          firebaseService.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
          await firebaseService.firestore.collection('businessesPendingAdminApproval').add(values)
        }

        writeToFirebase()

        async function sendToFirebaseImageBucket(photo, uid) {
          const businessRef = await firebaseService.firestore.doc(
            `businessesPendingAdminApproval/${uid}`,
          )
          firebaseService.storage
            .ref()
            .child('businesses')
            .child(uid)
            .child('avatar-image')
            .put(photo)
            .then(response => response.ref.getDownloadURL())
            .then(photoURL => businessRef.update({ avatarImage: photoURL })) //try to update avatarImage
        }

        const uid = userObject.uid //undefined, can't get uid
        sendToFirebaseImageBucket(values.avatarImage, uid) //uid gets passed as undefined

      }}>
```

The way I am setting the `userObject` which is where I'm trying to get the uid from.

Setting the userObject eventually works but maybe not fast enought for me to be able to pass it to a function (as in the code above).

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseService.auth.onAuthStateChanged(async function (userAuth) {
      if (userAuth) {
        const user = await firebaseService.createUserProfileDocument(userAuth)
        setUserObject(user) //set userObject which has an uid field.
      } else {
        console.log('no one signed in')
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your image to cloud storage right after you have logged in and was able to get `uid`. the following code can help you, it works for me as well. put the following code inside `useEffect`.

```
const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user.uid){

       const ref = storage.ref(`images/${user.uid}`);
       const task = ref.putFile(_image, { contentType: 'image/jpeg' });

       task.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, snap => {

       setState({ type: 'cents', value: snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes * 100 });

      }, err => { console.log('Error in help:persisAppState: ', err) }, async () => {

            const image = await ref.getDownloadURL();

            if (image) await db.collection("imagelinks").doc(user.id).set({ image });
           });

    }
});
```